# Rails: am I nesting incorrectly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm currently working on my first project, and am trying to build the functionality first before doing the login/sessions. I'm trying to create a picture album website, where users have many albums (that contain many pictures), and album access is shared among friends. However, I'm noticing that after my `albums#create`

`http://localhost:3000/users/18/albums/new` (no problem here)

I am redirected to `albums#show`:

`http://localhost:3000/albums/20` (problem!!)

shouldn't there be a user_id in the URL as well?? Or does it not have a user_id attached to the URL because it belongs to multiple users? Here are my routes:

```
Pholder::Application.routes.draw do
resources :users do
  resources :albums 
end

resources :albums do
  resources :pictures
end

root :to => "users#index"
```

Here are my models in case:

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_secure_password
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create

  validates_format_of :name, :with => /[A-Za-z]+/, :on => :create
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create
  validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 5, :on => :create

  has_many :user_albums
  has_many :albums, :through => :user_albums
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :albums

end
```

album model

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar, :name, :description
  has_many :user_albums
  has_many :users, :through => :user_albums
  has_many :photos
end
```

photo album

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
end
```

albums controller

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @albums = Albums.all

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @albums }
      end
    end

    def show
      @albums = Album.all
      @album = Album.find(params[:id])
      @photo = Photo.new
    end

    def update
    end

    def edit
    end

    def create
      # @user = User.find(params[:albums][:user_id])
      # @users = User.all
      @album = Album.new(params[:album])
      # @album.user_id = @user.id
      respond_to do |format|
        if @album.save
          format.html { redirect_to @album, notice: 'Album was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @album, status: :created, location: @album}
        else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end 
    end

    def new
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @album = Album.new
    end

    def destroy
    end


end
```

Let me know if you need any other files.

Comment: Well, if the problem is redirection, it is in the controller.

Comment: I uploaded the albums controller so you could see. Is the @album instance variable wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The line `redirect_to @album` makes you redirect to the `show` action of the `@album` in question.
Changing this piece of code to something like `redirect_to users_path` will make the app redirect to the `index` action of `users_controller` and so on.
It depends on whatever behavior you want after the save.

Reading this should be helpful too: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: is there a reason why the URL takes out the user_id though?

Comment: Yeah, if you do a `rake routes | grep album` you will see all available routes with the album in it. You have a nested resource album inside user, so if you put something like this `user_albuns_path(:user_id => @user.id, :id => @album.id)` you will have the desired route.